# Splitting Reducer output in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

The output files produced by my Reduce operation is huge (1 GB after Gzipping). I want it produce break output into smaller files of 200 MB. Is there a property/Java class to split reduce output by size or no. of lines ? 
I can not increase the number of reducers because that has negative impact on performance of the hadoop job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious as to why you cannot just use more reducers, but I will take you at your word.

One option you can do is use MultipleOutputs and write to multiple files from one reducer. For example, say that the output file for each reducer is 1GB and you want 256MB files instead. This means you need to write 4 files per reducer rather than one file.

In your job driver, do this:

```
JobConf conf = ...;

// You should probably pass this in as parameter rather than hardcoding 4.
conf.setInt("outputs.per.reducer", 4);

// This sets up the infrastructure to write multiple files per reducer.
MultipleOutputs.addMultiNamedOutput(conf, "multi", YourOutputFormat.class, YourKey.class, YourValue.class);
```

In your reducer, do this:

```
@Override
public void configure(JobConf conf) {
  numFiles = conf.getInt("outputs.per.reducer", 1);
  multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs(conf);

  // other init stuff
  ...
}

@Override
public void reduce(YourKey key
                   Iterator<YourValue> valuesIter,
                   OutputCollector<OutKey, OutVal> ignoreThis,
                   Reporter reporter) {
    // Do your business logic just as you're doing currently.
    OutKey outputKey = ...;
    OutVal outputVal = ...;

    // Now this is where it gets interesting. Hash the value to find
    // which output file the data should be written to. Don't use the
    // key since all the data will be written to one file if the number
    // of reducers is a multiple of numFiles.
    int fileIndex = (outputVal.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numFiles;

    // Now use multiple outputs to actually write the data.
    // This will create output files named: multi_0-r-00000, multi_1-r-00000,
    // multi_2-r-00000, multi_3-r-00000 for reducer 0. For reducer 1, the files
    // will be multi_0-r-00001, multi_1-r-00001, multi_2-r-00001, multi_3-r-00001.
    multipleOutputs.getCollector("multi", Integer.toString(fileIndex), reporter)
      .collect(outputKey, outputValue);
}

@Overrider
public void close() {
   // You must do this!!!!
   multipleOutputs.close();
}
```

This pseudo code was written with the old mapreduce api in mind. Equivalent apis exist using the mapreduce api, though, so either way, you should be all set.

Comment: I can't increase the number of reducers because it makes the job slow as more shuffling of data needs to be done. I have confirmed this in theory and in practice. However I your proposed solution. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There's no property to do this. You'll need to write your own output format & record writer.